# Python – Getting incorrect interval timelines in yfinance package

Tags: python, yfinance

I am using the yfinance package in Python to find the differences between the latest stock price and the price an hour beforehand. But when I set the interval to 1h, the bottom interval is set to 30m, then all intervals are 1h from that point. Does anyone know how to fix this behavior?

```
>>> yf.download(tickers = 'AAPL', period = '2h', interval = '1h')
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
                                 Open        High  ...   Adj Close    Volume
2022-07-27 13:30:00-04:00  154.401993  155.000000  ...  154.455002   3762267
2022-07-27 14:30:00-04:00  154.455002  157.289902  ...  157.289902  13695565
2022-07-27 15:30:00-04:00  157.289993  157.330002  ...  156.699997  12040745
2022-07-27 16:00:00-04:00  156.789993  156.789993  ...  156.789993         0
```

As you can see, the bottom row is for 16:00:00, which is closing time for the stock market. But oddly the row up is 15:30:00, when it should be 15:00:00 because I have set the interval at 1h. Also you will notice it pulls 4 rows of data when it should only be 2 because I set the total period to 2h. Here is the result I am looking for:

```
>>> yf.download(tickers = 'AAPL', period = '2h', interval = '1h')
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
                                 Open        High  ...   Adj Close    Volume
2022-07-27 15:00:00-04:00  155.919998  157.289902  ...  157.289902   6613863
2022-07-27 16:00:00-04:00  156.789993  156.789993  ...  156.789993         0
```

I have tried setting the interval time to 60m instead of 1h and I get the same result. The same issue also occurs when I set the interval time to 90m: the bottom interval gets set to 30m.

Can anyone explain this behavior to me? Thanks.

Comment: I think this may be an effect of the 10:30 opening time. The following code specifies the first and the last time since you can get 15:00, 15:30, and 16:00. `yf.download(tickers='AAPL', period='1h', interval='30m').iloc[[0,-1],]`

Comment: Yep that makes sense. I am wondering if there is a way for yfinance to count the time backwards from the current time instead of forwards from 9:30…